# Resize ListView Element While Viewing in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, resize

What I am trying to do is populate a listView with views/elements that could be a textview/imageview. Potentially, these textviews are expandable. I want the listview to resize and wrap the content if the textview is expanded.

There are several solutions out there already:
1. Make the elements of the ListView element invisible so that the view in ListView is already the size you want. In this case, create the text view with the original long string and then collapse it.
2. Resize the element in the adapter then call notifyDataSetChanged();

However I'm looking for a solution where the view in ListView automatically resizes, even when its visible. I have tried using Solution #2 and while it works for changing values inside the view such as a string, it doesn't resize the view altogether unless the view is scrolled off screen then comes back into view.

The relevant part of my code is as follows:

```
holder.text.setTrim(!holder.text.getTrim());
holder.text.setText();
holder.text.requestFocusFromTouch();
notifyDataSetChanged();
holder.text.invalidate();
vi.invalidate();
vi.requestLayout();
```

I put this inside an OnClickListener inside an adapter's getView function.

Anyone have any solutions?

PS. Has anyone tried doing a method with multiple adapters? This one doesnt seem to work too well for me because I have potentially hundreds of elements.

Edit:
So I've come up with part of a stupid solution that is absolutely ridiculous. The behavior makes no sense. Below (primaryTextView is the same text as above eg. holder.primaryTextView == holder.text)

```
holder.primaryTextView.setTrim(!holder.primaryTextView.getTrim());
if(!holder.primaryTextView.getTrim()){
holder.primaryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else{
holder.primaryTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
vi.invalidate();
```

This allows you to expand the view while viewing it but does not allow you to shrink the view once the text is collapsed. Furthermore, View.GONE and View.VISIBLE are NOT interchangable. Finally, the textView does not even dissapear in the event that View.GONE is triggered. Perhaps this might be a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind found the problem:
In my layout, I was using height="0dp" instead of "wrap_content"

Comment: I was using `match_parent` and the parent had `wrap_content`.  Led to the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> *it doesn't resize the view altogether unless the view is scrolled off screen then comes back into view.*

It is working, but you are not refreshing the listview, when you scroll off & return, listview **recreates** the updated view.

You should [notifyDataSetChanged();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I am actually calling notifyDataSetChanged(); from within my adapter. It is in the pasted code I put.

The pasted code I put was the code that was inside my onClickListener.